# Move span in the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

just want to move 'More...' at the bottom of the box:
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/cHKF4/12/)

```
  <div id="box1">
  <span class="more">More...</span>
  </div>


.more {
    margin: 4px 4px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#box1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #55fff3;
    height: 120px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set absolute positioning on the span, and relative positioning on the bounding box.

```
<div id="box1">
    <span class="more">More...</span>
</div>


.more {
    margin: 4px 4px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

#box1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #55fff3;
    height: 120px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
```

See the [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cHKF4/13/) for a live example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `position: absolute` for `more span`

Live:

http://jsfiddle.net/cHKF4/16/

You can look at here for using **position**.

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/